# Java leap year if-else statement getting stuck

Tags: java

My assignment for school is to write a program in java that accepts a four-digit entry from System.in.read(); and calculates whether or not it is a leap year, and then tells the user whether or not it is a leap year, then presents the option to restart the program. Also, if the user  enters a year before 1582 it will tell them of the error, followed by the program reset option.

Before I continue, I realize that there are much better ways to handle text input, in fact I wrote a whole program for this using scanner that worked beautifully but since we won't be covering that in class until next week, my teacher said I cannot use it.

This is the code I was given by my teacher to handle the text entry.

```
     // Program using read() method to read 4 consecutive characters and convert to a year
 // JAK

 class ReadLeapYear {

       public static void main(String args[])
            throws java.io.IOException {

            char restartChoice;
            int readCh, year=0, i;

            do
            {

            System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
            readCh =  (int)System.in.read();
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: year = (int)((readCh - 48) * 1000); break;
                case 1: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100); break;
                case 2: year = year + (int)((readCh - 48) * 10); break;
                case 3: year = year + (int) (readCh-48);
            } // end switch
           } // end for

            System.out.println(year);
           readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the carriage return in the buffer
           readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the linefeed in the buffer

            year = 0; // Reset year for another choice
            System.out.print("Do you wish to test another year? Y/N \n");
            restartChoice=(char)System.in.read();
            }while(restartChoice == 'Y');
        }                                                                       //end main
}                                                                               //end class
```

And below is the code I've written so far, which as far as I can tell should work fine based on the logic of my previous works.

```
package revisedleapyear;


public class RevisedLeapYear {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

    char restartChoice = 'y';
    int readCh, year=0, i;
    boolean isLeapYear;

    while(restartChoice == 'y' || restartChoice == 'Y'){
        System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)//start for
        {
            readCh = (int)System.in.read();
            switch(i) //start switch
            {//converts in to 4 digits
                case 0: year = (int)((readCh - 48) * 1000); break;
                case 1: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100); break;
                case 2: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 10); break;
                case 3: year = year + (int) (readCh - 48);
            }//end switch
    }//end for
        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
            if(year < 1582){
                System.out.println("There are no leap years before 1582! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
            else if(isLeapYear == true && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
                else if(isLeapYear == false && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate. \nPress Enter to continue.");
            }
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the carriage return in the buffer
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the linefeed in the buffer

    System.out.print("Reset program? y/n \n");
    restartChoice=(char)System.in.read();

    }              
}
}
```

I'm encountering two problems right now. The first problem is that it always decides that any number I give it from 1582 and higher is a leap year. The second problem is that if I choose a number lower than 1582 and then restart the program, it will always act as if I've chosen 1582.

Here is an example of the program log, producing these errors.

```
> Enter target year: 2004 
> 2004 is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive! 
> Press Enter to continue.
> 
> Reset program? y/n  
> y Enter target year: 2001 
> There are no leap years before 1582!  
> Press Enter to continue. 
> Reset program? y/n
```

EDIT: I've fixed the problem where it was only declaring things as leap years. But now no matter what, if I restart the program the second output will always say that I chose a date before 1582, even though I did not.

Comment: Please indent your code properly to make it readable.

Comment: use `isLeapYear == true` or just `isLeapYear`. `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: Your teacher's code is very ugly XD

Comment: never code `if (isLeapYear = true)` (bug - always `true` and assigns `true` to variable) or even `if (isLeapYear == true)` (not a bug, but visually almost indistinguishable from a bug). Code `if (isLeapYear)` - clean, simple and bugless.